# Which mining pools use custom mining software?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-software

Which mining pools use custom mining software? Do those pools require the users to use their software, or just encourage their users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BitMinter](http://bitminter.com) offers its own mining software, but also gives the option of using other programs by connecting to mint.bitminter.com:8332 .